# How to identify game controller for SDL2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: gamepad, uuid

I'm trying to make Costume Quest (game by Double Fine) use either of my gamepads and according to developer's [support](http://steamcommunity.com/app/115100/discussions/0/828938532534789112/) all I need to do is add SDL2 config line to `SDLGamepad.config` file, however, I can't find the correct values for UUID. None of the values provided by `lsusb`, `dmesg` or `udevadm` match examples (below) where UUID is 32 chars long (first column):

```
030000006d0400001ec2000020200000,Logitech Rumble Gamepad F510(Linux),a:b0,b:b1,x:b2,y:b3,start:b7,back:b6,guide:b8,leftstick:b9,rightstick:b10,leftshoulder:b4,rightshoulder:b5,dpup:h0.1,dpleft:h0.8,dpdown:h0.4,dpright:h0.2,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a3,righty:a4,lefttrigger:a2,righttrigger:a5,
030000005e0400008e02000014010000,Microsoft Xbox 360 Gamepad (xpad) (Linux),a:b0,b:b1,y:b3,x:b2,start:b7,guide:b8,back:b6,leftstick:b9,rightstick:b10,leftshoulder:b4,rightshoulder:b5,dpup:h0.1,dpleft:h0.8,dpdown:h0.4,dpright:h0.2,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a3,righty:a4,lefttrigger:a2,righttrigger:a5,
```

What should I use there? My config file entries don't work:

```
0003:0E8F:0012.0016,GreenAsia Inc. USB Wireless 2.4GHz Gamepad,a:b1,b:b2,y:b3,x:b0,start:b9,guide:b13,back:b8,leftstick:b10,rightstick:b11,leftshoulder:b4,rightshoulder:b5,dpup:h0.1,dpleft:h0.8,dpdown:h0.4,dpright:h0.2,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a2,righty:a3,lefttrigger:b6,righttrigger:b7,
0003:0079:0006.0011,DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick,a:b1,b:b2,y:b3,x:b0,start:b9,guide:b13,back:b8,leftstick:b10,rightstick:b11,leftshoulder:b4,rightshoulder:b5,dpup:h0.1,dpleft:h0.8,dpdown:h0.4,dpright:h0.2,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a3,righty:a4,lefttrigger:b6,righttrigger:b7,
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 049: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick
Bus 002 Device 048: ID 0e8f:0012 GreenAsia Inc. USB Wireless 2.4GHz Gamepad
```

==== edit ====

In case someone came here only for this, this is my GreenAsia Inc. config, working on Linux using xpad:

```
030000008f0e00001200000010010000,GreenAsia Inc.,a:b2,b:b1,y:b0,x:b3,start:b9,guide:,back:b8,leftstick:b10,rightstick:b11,leftshoulder:b6,rightshoulder:b7,dpup:h0.1,dpleft:h0.8,dpdown:h0.4,dpright:h0.2,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a2,righty:a3,lefttrigger:b4,righttrigger:b5,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone wants to know the SDL gamepad number, just install the program `antimicro` (you can use `sudo apt install antimicro`) and click in **Controller Mapping**.

Comment: Simplest solution so far for a common user so yes, this is an accepted answer now. Sorry Grumbel and Tak.

Comment: I should also suggest this, but antimicro is quite buggy. Also the number used by this soft are very confusing, for example axis0 in sdl is called axis 1 in antimicro! :(

Answer (score 5):

The GUID is an SDL2 specific ID, there is no direct way to get it with system tool. The GUID is build by squishing the bus, vendor, product and version numbers into a single value, you can see it here:

http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/a9d1c47bb1aa/src/joystick/linux/SDL_sysjoystick.c#l117

One way to get it is by reading it from SDL. The following program does that, compile it with:

```
gcc -o sdl2-joystick sdl2-joystick.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2`
```

Save the following as `sdl2-joystick.c`:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main()
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);
  atexit(SDL_Quit);

  int num_joysticks = SDL_NumJoysticks();
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < num_joysticks; ++i)
  {
    SDL_Joystick* js = SDL_JoystickOpen(i);
    if (js)
    {
      SDL_JoystickGUID guid = SDL_JoystickGetGUID(js);
      char guid_str[1024];
      SDL_JoystickGetGUIDString(guid, guid_str, sizeof(guid_str));
      const char* name = SDL_JoystickName(js);

      int num_axes = SDL_JoystickNumAxes(js);
      int num_buttons = SDL_JoystickNumButtons(js);
      int num_hats = SDL_JoystickNumHats(js);
      int num_balls = SDL_JoystickNumBalls(js);

      printf("%s \"%s\" axes:%d buttons:%d hats:%d balls:%d\n", 
             guid_str, name,
             num_axes, num_buttons, num_hats, num_balls);

      SDL_JoystickClose(js);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and of course you're right about UUID being an SDL2 specific value. Devs from DF should consider including config wizard in their games instead of "outsourcing" this task to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Steams Big Picture Mode and configure your controller there? As far as I understand Steam will automatically generate the SDL2 config that way and hand it over to the game.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, however, it would be awesome to know how to get this value on system level.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this - here's a ruby script that doesn't require any compiler knowhow: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~taktaktaktaktaktaktaktaktaktak/+junk/joystickguid/view/head:/joystickguid.rb

Comment: Yes, it should be - at least, it matches the sdl2 id for my gamepads.

Comment: Not need to compile but need ruby